# Problems faced when writing a compiler for C

Tags: c, compiler-construction

Can someone list the problems faced by people while developing compilers for the C programming language (NOT C++)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is far too general a question. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Asked 30 years too late.

Comment: I recommend reading "Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools".

Comment: @Hans: and yet, questions about implementing linked lists are asked and answered here seemingly every other day.

Comment: C99 or C89? Since Codo's answer mentions Microsoft's compiler as "state of the art", that must assume C89. C99 introduces new features, which are new challenges if not new problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a summary of the status of C99 support in GCC.

http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html

I think these can be considered "problems" which one particular group of people has encountered writing their C compiler, although I believe most or all of them are/were only problems because GCC supports many platforms - solving them one platform at a time would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

With today's solid theory about compiler construction, writing a C compiler isn't that difficult for an experienced programmer. The produced code will nicely work but won't be anywhere as efficient as those produced by state of the art compilers like Intel's, Microsoft's or gcc.

I'd probably be more challenged by writing the preprocessor...

Comment: Really? I thought preprocessing C files conists mostly of string replacements (with some extensions).

Comment: That's what I thought as well until I had to fixed a bunch of macros that used all sorts of tricks... I should probably write a preprocessor so that I finally fully understand macros.